# Delphi find underline in string

Tags: string, delphi, search

I have two strings named "ver1" and "ver2" the input in the strings looks like this:

`Ver1: B2CD1`        `Ver2: B3A10`

Sometimes it looks like this:

`Ver1: B2CD1_A1`        `Ver2: B3A10_DE`

My question: How can I search in both strings after the "_" in it and return a value from it?

By the way the function is for software version comparison. Please just give me advice in my question not my entire function.

Thanks

```
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, StrUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;


type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

function isSoftwareGreater(ver1,ver2 : string) : byte;
var i : integer;
    tmp1,tmp2 : string;
    cver1,cver2 : int64;

begin
{
  Return values:
      0: versions are equal
      1: ver1 is bigger then ver2
      2: ver2 is bigger then ver1
    253: ver1 is too big (could not be converted to int64)
    254: ver2 is too big (could not be converted to int64)
}

  tmp1 := '';
  tmp2 := '';

  for i := 1 to length(ver1) do
   begin
    if (ver1[i] in ['a'..'z']) or (ver1[i] in ['A'..'Z']) then
     tmp1 := tmp1 + inttostr(Ord(ver1[i]));
    if (ver1[i] in ['0'..'9']) then
     tmp1 := tmp1 + ver1[i];
   end;
  for i := 1 to length(ver2) do
   begin
    if (ver2[i] in ['a'..'z']) or (ver2[i] in ['A'..'Z']) then
     tmp2 := tmp2 + inttostr(Ord(ver2[i]));
    if (ver2[i] in ['0'..'9']) then
     tmp2 := tmp2 + ver2[i];
   end;

  if not TryStrToInt64(tmp2,cver2) then
   begin
    isSoftwareGreater := 254;
    exit;
   end;
  if not TryStrToInt64(tmp1,cver1) then
   begin
    isSoftwareGreater := 253;
    exit;
   end;

  if ver1 > ver2 then
    isSoftwareGreater := 1
  else if ver2 > ver1 then
    isSoftwareGreater := 2
  else if ver1 = ver2 then
    isSoftwareGreater := 0;

end;
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`Pos`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) function?

Comment: No did you have an example for me? (sorry i am pretty new to delphi btw)

Comment: To mark the Q as "solved", you should click the check mark next to the answer that you prefer.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search a string using the [Pos() function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Pos). It returns the index of the found character or 0 if not found.

```
var
    Index     : Integer;
    SubString : String;
begin
    Index := Pos('_', Ver1);
    if Index > 0 then
        SubString := Copy(Ver1, Index + 1, MAXINT)
    else
        SubString := '';
end;
```

If you want to extract text between two markers, you have to search for the first as shown above and then search for the second, starting right after the first one. Pos() has an optional 3rd argument to specify where to start search. This gives:

```
var
    Index1    : Integer;
    Index2    : Integer;
    SubString : String;
begin
    Index1 := Pos('_', Ver1);
    if Index1 > 0 then begin
        Index2 := Pos('_', Ver1, Index1 + 1);
        if Index2 > 0 then
            // We have two underscore, extract text between them
            SubString := Copy(Ver1, Index1 + 1, Index2 - Index1 - 1)
        else
            // Only one underscore, extract text from the first to the end of string
            SubString := Copy(Ver1, Index1 + 1, MAXINT);
    end
    else
        SubString := '';
end;
```

Comment: Actually, you can omit `MAXINT` (the entire argument).

Comment: @liko Is this related to the question/answer or is it a new question? If new question, please write a new StackOverflow question (More info than what you show). If not new question, then I don't understand what you mean. Please reformulate.

Comment: @fpiette this is related to your answer. I have two underlines in my string and want to find them both. What did i need to change? I only find the first underline in the string.

Comment: @Liko The next time you write a question, be more precise about what you really want to do. This being said, I edited my answer to add an example of what you ask. You could have worked a little bit, read the doc and done it yourself! StackOverflow is not a website to request someone to write code for you...

Comment: @fpiette thanks a lot! I worked a simmiliar code out. Now that i have an example of your code i can see what i missed. I am sorry next time i will do more research and not write a new qouestions after a few Errors!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ContainsStr()` to check if the strings has `'_'` and then use `SubString()` and `IndexOf()`

```
function GetString(const AString, ASubString: string): string;
begin
  Result:= EmptyStr;
  if ContainsStr(AString, ASubString) then
    Result:= AString.Substring(Astring.IndexOf(ASubString)+1, AString.Length);
end;
```

Comment: Even nicer: `if MyString.Contains('_') then ...`

Comment: Yeah @AndreasRejbrand that one too.

Comment: This is very inefficient. The string is scanned twice for the underline character: one for ContainsStr and one for IndexOf.